# Jquery - Changing image attributes

Tags: jquery

I have an image, which contains the following:

`<img src="/Modules/Visualiser.php?template=1&text=testing">`

What I need to do, is when a dropdown has been changed, it changes the `template` depending on the selection. But I can't seem to figure out how to just change the template, since the text will stay the same (At this point anyway)..

```
$("#select-cover").change(function()
    {
        $("#cover-photo").attr('src', function(i, src) {
             return src.replace( 'template=', 'template=1' );
        }); 
    });
```

I have tried to do this, but had no joy. Any have any ideas to where I am going wrong?

Comment: How does the dropdown look like? Add it above. Also, what output do you expect because your code seems working?

Comment: @ShaunakD What use would the dropdown look like? The problem that I am having is the fact I cannot change the individual pieces of the image src

Comment: What do you want to change it into? Do you want to assign dropdown value to `template`? This  was my assumption.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery loaded correctly? Check your errors in the browser log

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the template param like

```
$("#select-cover").change(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    $("#cover-photo").attr('src', function (i, src) {
        return src.replace(/\?template=\d+/, '?template=' + value);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/snz7o1Le/) - inspect the element to see the difference

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If you could, how would I therefore change the text?

Comment: @Phorce change to what

Comment: Well let's say that I have a text box and wanted to change the value of the text `&text=testing` if I input into the textbox `&text=HELLO` it would change - not the `template` but just the text?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the select provides the template number eg (1, 2, 3 etc):

```
$('#select-cover').on('change', function() {
   var tempNum = $(this).val();
   $('#cover-photo').attr('src', '/Modules/Visualiser.php?template=' + tempNum + '&text=testing');
});
```